# Insert data into SQL Server table from Jdeveloper 11g

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jdeveloper

I am trying to insert data into a SQL Server table from Jdeveloper 11g, but somehow it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
public void theQuery(String query) {   
    Statement statement = null;            
    Connection connection = null;  

    try {                 
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/PROGRAII","root",""); 
         statement = connection.createStatement();                   
         statement.executeUpdate(query);                     
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se realizó la operación");            
     }            
     catch (Exception ex) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NO se realizó la operación"); 
     }                 
}
```

And this is the string:

```
private void jButAceptar_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        
 try {             
inserta.theQuery("insert into ControlAcceso(cedula,email,clave) values('"+this.jTexCedula.getText()+"'," +                      ","+this.jTexEmail.getText()+"','"+this.jTexClave.getText()+"')");                 } catch (Exception ex) {            
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se realizo el query");         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace `","+this.jTexEmail.getText()` to `"'"+this.jTexEmail.getText()`.